# Storing data in partition table versus non partitioned tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pull billions of records from source tables and storing them in multiple destination tables which would stored based on year and quarter.

I have looked into the option of partitioning destination table and realized that it occupies more space compared to storing data in non partitioned tables.

The only difference between the migration that i ran on the partition table versus the migration than ran on non partitioned  tables is that later had three columns less.

The size of the disk after running the same query were as follows

Migration on partition table - 9 TB
Migration on multiple non partitioned tables - 1 TB

Could somebody tell me if partitioning tables create a bigger footprint

The query

```
SELECT  
    fc.financialCollectionId,
    fp.companyid,
    fd.dataitemid,
    di.dataitemname,    
    fd.dataitemvalue,
    fu.unittypevalue,
    fp.fiscalyear,
    fp.fiscalquarter,
    fi.periodenddate,
    fi.filingdate,
    rt.restatementtypename,
    fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag,
    fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag,
    conv.currencyconversionflag,
    cur.currencyname, 
    pt.periodtypename



from 
    ciqfinperiod fp 

    join ciqperiodtype pt on pt.periodtypeid = fp.periodtypeid 
    join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
    left join ciqrestatementtype rt on rt.restatementtypeid = fi.restatementtypeid
    join ciqfininstancetocollection ic on ic.financialinstanceid = fi.financialinstanceid
    inner join ciqfincollection fc on fc.financialcollectionid = ic.financialcollectionid
    inner join ciqfincollectiondata fd on
        fd.financialcollectionid = fc.financialcollectionid
    inner join ciqdataitemconversionrule conv on conv.dataitemid = fd.dataitemid
    inner join ciqcurrency cur on cur.currencyid = fc.currencyid
    inner join ciqdataitem di on di.dataitemid= fd.dataitemid
    inner join ciqfinunittype fu on fu.unittypeid =fd.unittypeid
@maxFiscalQuarter

    where year(fi.periodEndDate) >=  2000
```

Comment: mysql != sql-server - please tag correctly

Comment: Aligned partitioned tables with the same schema and indexes should not require significantly more space than equivalent non-partitioned tables. Can you post the DDL for both?

Comment: Added the query which i used for both migrations

Comment: Something else to consider: how often do you need to change / update / delete records from these tables? This is something where the partitioned tables bring some benefit... they might require more space but the tasks at hand are way faster...